# How can you stop Visual Studio rearranging its Windows when debugging

Tags: visual-studio

Does anyone know whether it's possible to stop Visual Studio 2010 from rearranging its windows when you run a program in the debugger?

It's something that Visual Studio versions have done for as long as I remember - if I've understood it correctly, it has two settings for how to arrange its Windows - one for when it's in the debugger and one for when it isn't, and as soon as you start/stop the debugger it swaps between them. I've always found this a bit annoying - partly because if I want to put a particular Window somewhere, I don't want to have to separately tell VS to put it there twice (once in the debugger and once not) and partly because usually if I'm starting the program, it DOESN'T mean I also want to immediately lose my view of the bit of code I happened to be looking at just prior to hitting F5.  So - anyone know if it's possible to switch that feature off, and have just one single arrangement of Windows?

Comment: It is being asked to add an option to not differentiate them in MS Developer Community https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/disable-specifik-debug-viewwindows-layout-let-it-f/1562764

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to turn this off as it is by desgin.

Visual Studio comes with 4 window layouts: Design, Debug, Full Screen Mode, and File mode.  You can get see more info some examples here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/21/window-layouts-the-four-modes-vstipenv0051.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/22/window-layouts-design-debug-and-full-screen-vstipenv0052.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/23/window-layouts-file-view-vstipenv0053.aspx

Comment: Visual studio is just something else I tell you :|