# How can I prevent Visual Studio from switching perspective in Debug mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you stop Visual Studio rearranging its Windows when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838109/how-can-you-stop-visual-studio-rearranging-its-windows-when-debugging)

Whenever I start debugging an application, Visual Studio moves my cheese.

How can I make it leave my cheese alone?

Comment: "Who moved my cheese" is a phrase indicating that I am resistant to change.  That is, I am like a mouse in a maze, and if my cheese is moved, I have to find it again.

Comment: In this particular case, my "cheese" would be all of the window arrangements and visibility.  I would like to leave all of that alone when I switch modes.

Comment: Is there an IDE that doesn't do this?

Comment: @MichaelBurr IntelliJ IDEA for Java development leaves the windows as-is while debugging. Superb in my opinion.

Comment: @maba: so what does IDEA do with the various debugging-specific windows, like watch or call stack?  Do you have to open them explicitly every time you start debugging or are they there (but empty?) when you're not debugging?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only solution is that you must arrange things twice. Afterwards it won't move "your cheese" except as you expected it.

Edit: duplicate of [How can you stop Visual Studio rearranging its Windows when debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838109/how-can-you-stop-visual-studio-rearranging-its-windows-when-debugging)

Comment: It actually moves. If I had one tab opened in the Debug mode and another in the Type mode, then switching modes will jump those tabs.

Answer (score 2):

This is a "feature" actually.  The presumption is that you would want a different layout when debugging (ie, watch windows visible in debug, but not coding).  I don't think there's a way to prevent it other than going into debug and manually moving things to match your coding layout.